# porting network application from pc posix (linux) to STM32 / lwip

Tags: linux, networking, lwip

I want to port my pc based source code which is a network application that uses posix standard to a cortex M4 microcontroller using LWIP stack.
I have found the sockets related APIs but I am stuck in the following includes:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>       ==> I have not found the equivalent in LWIP
#include <netinet/in_systm.h> ==> I have not found the equivalent in LWIP
#include <netinet/ip.h>       ==> I have not found the equivalent in LWIP
#include <netinet/tcp.h>      ==> I have not found the equivalent in LWIP
#include <sys/socket.h> ==> I have found the equivalent in LWIP
#include <sys/sysctl.h> ==> I have found the equivalent in LWIP
```

So where can I find the source code in c language of the missed files? Are they aiavable on PC or on web...?
Is it possible to rewrite them?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

lwip does not have the same include file structure as typical BSD sockets.

Here's what I'd do:

1. comment or ifdef out standard networking include files,
2. include lwip's "api.h" instead
3. try to compile.
4. See what compiler complains about and grep for particular type in lwip's src/include and include appropriate LwIP's file.
5. Repeat 3-5 until compiler is happy.

Comment: Thanks ArtemB but your solution can be considered for simple packages.  What about a complex one? Is there a simpler method?

Comment: You can fake those includes. Create include file hierarchy matching expected one (i.e. sys/socket.h sys/sysctl.h netinet/ip.h ...) that would just include subset of LwIP's includes. It's probably not going to help you much as the code that really depends on standard UNIX sockets is likely to expect more data types and functionality that LwIP provides and you would still have to do at least some amount of porting.